# cakephp get the url of image from post

Tags: cakephp

I would get the image url: mysite/img/test.png 
 but I get this link:   mysite/posts/test.png

```
<?php echo $this->Html->link(
        $this->Html->image($post['Post']['image']),
        $post['Post']['title']),
        array('escape' => false)
        ); 
    ?>
```

I have to get another way the url?

Comment: In CakePHP 2 you can use IMAGES_URL to get the public image data path and then concatenate your path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit:

If you want link to your image, you can do in this way.

```
<?php echo $this->Html->link(
    $this->Html->image($post['Post']['image']),
    $this->Html->url('/img/'.$post['Post']['image']),
    array('escape' => false)
    ); 
?>
```

or

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->Html->url('/img/'.$post['Post']['image']); ?>">
<?php echo $this->Html->image($post['Post']['image']); ?>
</a>
```

Comment: If I might make a suggestion, some description of what your code does might help the questioner,

Comment: thank you for your answers . well it works . I'll also tried with constant IMAGES_URL